# android emulator issue

Tags: android, eclipse

I am modifying an existing app.And there is an issue trying to run ADT

**environment**

- Eclipse-galilo
- jdk 6
- ADT android sdk    lattest editon.

**error bellow**

```
[2010-11-19 11:01:12 - iDonatedIt] Android Launch!
[2010-11-19 11:01:12 - iDonatedIt] adb is running normally.
[2010-11-19 11:01:12 - iDonatedIt] Could not find iDonatedIt.apk!
```

I have loaded/reloaded the project. My other projects load just fine but this one will not at all. Any help on fixing the situation would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a fix. I had to copy the entire code folder, delete it, then place it back in my workplace.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project?

Comment: cleaning the project results in the same behavior

Comment: Then you should look at the project tree and see if the output file exists, also find the window with the build messages and see if it's being created.  Could be something odd like a directory/file permission or disk full preventing its creation.  Could also be a build error that isn't getting brought to your attention.  Or you could have a path name that can't be handled by some parts of the toolchain, such as one containing unusual characters or perhaps spaces.

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Actually it is an answer for unexplained tool misbehavior, as eclipse rebuilds projects automatically when they are cleaned.  Besides, the question has seen no activity for the greater part of two years; changing it now would not only be pointless but would erase the comments subsequently attached.

Comment: My point was rather to edit your answer, for example by merging your comment with the original answer. Sorry for the too generic comment that was added by the "Review" tool.

Comment: It's fine the way it is, thanks.  Perhaps you should focus your attention on more current topics.  This question itself is fairly specific to the poster's problem, but my answer is far more useful and should be a routine first step in the Android developer's response to the rather buggy tool set.